# Body not sending through Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-function-app

I have an Azure Function app running which works great, I send a JSON body through Postman and it works fine.
I am now trying to add Azure API Management in front of this for the added features. This has now stopped sending the JSON body through to the Function App. I get a response from the function app through the API Management with a response, basically telling me it is expecting something in the body.

[image]

As you can see, the body is null.
Am I missing something on the API Management side? I'm setting the header Content-Type to application/json

Please help me! :) I'm pulling my hair out and I bet I have just missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that if you submit a GET request. It does not send a body. I have changed this to POST and it worked perfectly.

Comment: That is correct, by design apim ignores body for Get and Head Requests.